# Prefetch all relationship instances without call .all()

Tags: python, django

I prefetch_related my objects with the following code:

```
    objs = wm.ModelA.objects.prefetch_related(
    'ModelB__ModelC')
```

and i want to iterate all ModelB from all objs and i do it with the following way

```
            for o in objs:
                for t in o.ModelB.all():
```

I noticed that in every iteration of e.ModelB.all() it calls the database. Is there a way to avoid this and bring all MobelB from the begining ?

Comment: You'll need to include more information. If you're just after `ModelB` objects then it might make more sense to start your query from `ModelB` in the first place

Comment: This would not call the db each time, that's the whole point of prefetch_related.